# Are there any guide books that give details of walks that are accessible to a wheelchair user in the Peak District (UK)

Tags: uk, hiking, accessibility, guidebooks, peak-district

Are there any guide books that give details of walks that are accessible to a wheelchair user in the Peak District (UK)?

For example the paths have a reasonable surface and there are no steps or stiles to get over.

(Give that such a "book" may be publish privately and hence not listed on Amazon, a simple internet search is not enough to answer this question.)

Comment: Have you seen http://walkswithwheelchairs.com/ ? The site also sells a small number of books that might be relevant

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there are many wheelchair accessible paths worth mentioning. I tried taking a children's buggy before, but that didn't work out very well.

Comment: @Grzenio, to begin with there are all the old railway lines, some of the canal towpaths are also not bad.  "All Terrain Pushchair Walks - Peak District" may help with a children buggy.

Comment: You can get the RADAR key region list for Northwest England  https://crm.disabilityrightsuk.org/national-key-scheme/radar-nks-key-and-region-list and use it in conjunction with the public toilets guide on the net http://www.peakdistrict.gov.uk/visiting/toilets Those places will have accessible footpaths.

Answer (score 5):

There are some paths which are deliberately maintained as Easy Going Trails and intended to be wheelchair-accessible. For the ones within the Sheffield area of the Peak District, you can send off for the council's Easy Going Trails Booklet: https://www.sheffield.gov.uk/roads/travel/walking/prow/easy-going-trails.html .